# Perl: info from database into a form(HTML)

Tags: html, mysql, forms, perl, cgi

I'm working on a very specific problem at my work place and have not been able to find answers for what I'm searching for

I'm looking to retrieve information from a MySQL DB and adding it to a form so it can be added(submitted) to a different DB, but before submitting the user needs to be able to make changes and add more data to the retrieved information form the first database.(imagine "copy and pasting if you will" from first database into the  HTML form without submitting, if it makes any sense)

I have the HTML button and the SQL statmenet ready but dont know where to go from here?

**HTML:**

```
print "   <div style=\"z-index:86;\" class=\"group-shell\">";
print "   <table>\n";
print "   <tr><td><input class=\"dial-red-button\" id=\"importFromCAD\"  type=\"submit\" value=\"Import Info\"></td></tr>\n";
```

**Perl SQL statement:**

```
    $sql_statement20 = "select * FROM CT_AL_CAD_ID where CAD='$CAD' ORDER BY KeyField DESC";
    $sth20 = $dbh->prepare($sql_statement20);
    $sth20->execute();
    $sth20->bind_columns(undef, \$ID_data[0], \$ID_data[1], \$ID_data[2], \$ID_data[3], \$ID_data[4], \$ID_data[5], \$ID_data[6], \$ID_data[7], \$ID_data[8], \$ID_data[9], \$ID_data[10], \$ID_data[11], \$ID_data[12]);

    $sth20->fetch();
```

I've been stuck on this problem for for a few days. Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Exactly HOW is this not working?

Comment: @MarcB how do I display the retrieved info from the database to the user in the form fields so it can be modified without the info being submitted to the second database first. also I have this jquery code for my button. hope it helps                                                                           '                                                                \$(document).ready(function() {

 \$('#importFromCAD').click(function () {
  \$('#importNav').val('');
  return true;
'

Comment: cross post at http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1168832

Answer (score 0):

Execute your SQL statement before you produce the HTML output. Then use the variable that contains your database data (`@ID_data`) in the HTML. Something like this:

```
print "   <div style=\"z-index:86;\" class=\"group-shell\">";
print "   <table>\n";
foreach (0 .. $#ID_data) {
  print "<tr><td>ID data $_:</td><td><input name=\"ID_data_$_\" value=\"$ID_data[$_]\"></td></tr>\n";
}
print "   <tr><td><input class=\"dial-red-button\" id=\"importFromCAD\"  type=\"submit\" value=\"Import Info\"></td></tr>\n";
```

Note that your code will be cleaner if you learn to use heredocs and `qq(...)`.

```
print <<END_OF_HTML;
<div style="z-index:86;" class="group-shell">
<table>
END_OF_HTML

foreach (0 .. $#ID_data) {
  print qq(<tr><td>ID data $_:</td><td><input name="ID_data_$_" value="$ID_data[$_]"></td></tr>\n);
}
print qq(<tr><td><input class="dial-red-button" id="importFromCAD"  type="submit" value="Import Info"></td></tr>\n);
```

And it will get even cleaner if you use [a templating engine](https://metacpan.org/release/Template-Toolkit).